# Purpose of uppercase VOID macro & INT typedef in winnt.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Anyone any clue as to why there is an uppercase `VOID` macro defined in the `winnt.h` header?

To make matters more confusing, `VOID` is a macro, whereas `CHAR`, `SHORT`, `INT`, and `LONG` are typedefs.

See the relevant excerpt from `winnt.h`:

```
#ifndef VOID
#define VOID void
typedef char CHAR;
typedef short SHORT;
typedef long LONG;
#if !defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef int INT;
#endif
#endif
```

A historical reason perhaps for doing `VOID* pointer` instead of `void* pointer`?

**EDIT**: What is even more troubling is to see people using `VOID` instead of `void` when doing Windows programming **today**. You can also see it as part of MSDN docs, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205867(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original reason is that the Win32 API was originally supposed to be language independent, so they made up their own names (following their naming convention), and then provided a C implementation of that. In reality, much of what they defined tends to be ignored by most people using other languages (and largely even by people using C, for that matter).

As far as why `VOID` is a `#define` instead of a `typedef`, that's pretty simple: the required `typedef` *would* be `typedef void VOID;`, but C (as "defined" by Microsoft's C compilers from that time) simply doesn't allow that, so they use a macro instead.

Comment: No, you have it backwards.  The required typedef would be `typedef void VOID`, which is perfectly allowed.  Try it.

Comment: I did have the typedef typed in backwards. Even when corrected, however, it's not allowed by Microsoft's compilers from that time, which (of course) is what Microsoft treated as the definition of C. Most compilers allowed it then, and Microsoft's do now, but I'm reasonably certain their older ones didn't.

Answer (score 19):

The Windows API is old. *Really* old. Older than the official C standard old.

This means that, at the start, the Windows API had to deal with all kinds of ancient C compilers, with different levels of language support. Some might not support `void`. Some might have an `int` type that's not compatible with what windows thought was `int`. Some might not understand `short`. As a workaround, the Windows API provides upper-case portable equivalents that are aliased to whatever works for that particular compiler.

Of course, with modern compilers, things have settled down quite a bit. Everyone supports `void`, for example. However, in order to maintain compatibility with old code that uses these upper-case macros, the `#define`s and `typedef`s have to remain.

Comment: Raymond Chen has a lot of interesting blog posts about the history of Windows.  Although he hasn't written about `VOID` as far as I'm aware, he has written about all of the boolean variants in Win32: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/28/10146459.aspx .

Comment: The two blog posts linked from Adam Rosenfield's comment are good, but they're specific to booleans, which is a specialized area.  Raymond Chen also wrote one that specifically addresses this question:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080325-00/?p=23013