# What is different between uppercase and lowercase data type?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, platform-sdk

For Example int and INT.
About this two i just know int is the fundamental type and INT is windows data type both gain 4 bytes in memory and INT is use with window API.

But i don't understand what is the major and proper different between both of them.

Help me to understand this both fully?

Comment: `int` are primitive data types provided by the language. `INT` appears like some defines or typedef which guarantee a fixed width `int` irrespectve of the implementation.

Comment: C++ data types are usually written in small letters (`int`). Types written in uppercase letters can be really anything (for example a type from some windows lib but it could as well be a `typedef int INT`)

Comment: ps: sorry, but there is no way to "fully understand" all possible data types. There are as many as you like and you can always add new ones (that do not have to follow any logic, e.g. `typedef double INT` is completely valid C++)

Comment: They are usually provided to define fixed type for a certain platform. Like Windows has in Windef.h. Could be useful for developers to navigate among data types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of uppercase VOID macro & INT typedef in winnt.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669078/purpose-of-uppercase-void-macro-int-typedef-in-winnt-h)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is a language keyword, `INT` is not.

The size and range of values that an `int` can take is constrained, but not fixed, by the C++ standard.

`INT` is a data type defined by Windows that is a 4 byte signed integral type with 2's complement.

With a MSVC compiler targetting Windows, it is probably `typedef`fed or `#define`d to `int`, since `int` in that case has the required characteristics.

Using `std::int32_t` would be preferable as it's multiplatform, although a compiler does not have to support it.

Comment: Sir, Why INT is typedef or #define?

Comment: Because it's not part of standard C++.